# Pandas Count frequency of values by column

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to apply several operations that I usually do easily in R to the sample dataset below, using Python/Pandas.

```
S1 S2 S3 S4 S5 S6 S7 S8 S9 S10
QUER.MAC 9 8 3 5 6 0 5 0 0 0
QUER.VEL 8 9 8 7 0 0 0 0 0 0
CARY.OVA 6 6 2 7 0 2 0 0 0 0
PRUN.SER 3 5 6 6 6 4 5 0 4 1
QUER.ALB 5 4 9 9 7 7 4 6 0 2
JUGL.NIG 2 0 0 0 3 5 6 4 3 0
QUER.RUB 3 4 0 6 9 8 7 6 4 3
JUGL.CIN 0 0 5 0 2 0 0 2 0 2
ULMU.AME 2 2 4 5 6 0 5 0 2 5
TILI.AME 0 0 0 0 2 7 6 6 7 6
ULMU.RUB 4 0 2 2 5 7 8 8 8 7
CARY.COR 0 0 0 0 0 5 6 4 0 3
OSTR.VIR 0 0 0 0 0 0 7 4 6 5
ACER.SAC 0 0 0 0 0 5 4 8 8 9
```

After reading the data from a text file with

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("sample.txt", header=0, index_col=0, delimiter=' ')
```

I want to: (1) get the frequency of values larger than zero for **each** column; (2) get the sum of values in each column; (3) find the maximum value in each column.

I managed to obtain (2) using

```
N = df.apply(lambda x: np.sum(x))
```

But could not figure out how to achieve (1) and (3).

I need generic solutions, that are not dependent on the names of the columns, because I want to apply these operations on any number of similar matrices (which of course will have different labels and numbers of columns/rows).

Thanks in advance for any hints and suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Your 1st

```
df.gt(0).sum()
```

2nd

```
df.sum()
```

3rd

```
df.max()
```

Comment: Thanks. But what do "gt(0)" means? The member functions sum() and max() are also really handy.

Comment: @maurobio `gt`= `>` so `df.gt(0)`=`(df>0)`

Comment: Yep! I figure out this a few minutes ago! It's like the old conditional operators in FORTRAN. ;-)

Comment: @maurobio yep you got it：-）

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mask` and `describe` to get a bunch of stats by column.

```
df.mask(df <= 0).describe().T
```

Output:

```
     count      mean       std  min   25%  50%   75%  max
S1     9.0  4.666667  2.549510  2.0  3.00  4.0  6.00  9.0
S2     7.0  5.428571  2.439750  2.0  4.00  5.0  7.00  9.0
S3     8.0  4.875000  2.642374  2.0  2.75  4.5  6.50  9.0
S4     8.0  5.875000  2.031010  2.0  5.00  6.0  7.00  9.0
S5     9.0  5.111111  2.368778  2.0  3.00  6.0  6.00  9.0
S6     9.0  5.555556  1.878238  2.0  5.00  5.0  7.00  8.0
S7    11.0  5.727273  1.272078  4.0  5.00  6.0  6.50  8.0
S8     9.0  5.333333  2.000000  2.0  4.00  6.0  6.00  8.0
S9     8.0  5.250000  2.314550  2.0  3.75  5.0  7.25  8.0
S10   10.0  4.300000  2.540779  1.0  2.25  4.0  5.75  9.0
```

The reason to use mask is that `count` counts all non-NaN values, so masking anything that is < or = to 0 will make then NaN for `count`.

And, finally, we can add "sum" too, using `assign`:

```
df.mask(df<=0).describe().T.assign(sum=df.sum())
```

Output:

```
     count      mean       std  min   25%  50%   75%  max  sum
S1     9.0  4.666667  2.549510  2.0  3.00  4.0  6.00  9.0   42
S2     7.0  5.428571  2.439750  2.0  4.00  5.0  7.00  9.0   38
S3     8.0  4.875000  2.642374  2.0  2.75  4.5  6.50  9.0   39
S4     8.0  5.875000  2.031010  2.0  5.00  6.0  7.00  9.0   47
S5     9.0  5.111111  2.368778  2.0  3.00  6.0  6.00  9.0   46
S6     9.0  5.555556  1.878238  2.0  5.00  5.0  7.00  8.0   50
S7    11.0  5.727273  1.272078  4.0  5.00  6.0  6.50  8.0   63
S8     9.0  5.333333  2.000000  2.0  4.00  6.0  6.00  8.0   48
S9     8.0  5.250000  2.314550  2.0  3.75  5.0  7.25  8.0   42
S10   10.0  4.300000  2.540779  1.0  2.25  4.0  5.75  9.0   43
```